# Authentication from Wordpress for express.static

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, nginx

I've built a single page application hosted on a subdomain. A couple html pages are served via express.static. The subdomain is something like below. I am using NGINX for the SSL

spa.example.com

There's another company building the website at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). They're using wordpress. My SPA will be linked from their website. Once someone comes from example.com to my site, is there a way for me to determine whether or not they're logged in and details? I would route things differently in express.static depending on if they're logged in etc. I am a NOOB when it comes to authentication headers etc.

Comment: Effectively, you want to authenticate users of _your_ website with a logon flow to the wordpress website. That's like the "Login with Wordpress" button described [here](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-oauth-20-server/).

Comment: You can create a middleware on top of the static URL and do the authentication right?

Comment: Yes, `app.use("/htmlpages", login_with_wordpress, express.static("/path/to/htmlpages"))`